# Add block magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

how to add a block with a picture to the left sidebar in the standard magento Luma theme in magento, as shown in the picture

[image]

I tried this method

`app/design/frontend/TestTheme/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                    <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo.svg</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

but this don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Magento_Theme
---layout
-----default.xml
---youtemps
-----img.phtml
```

mb is not the best implementation, but this method will bring you the text, unfortunately the picture I can not tell you how to display without demo.

I hope you will be told how to improve the method, or try to finish my task based on my code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <container name="sidebar.img.container" htmlClass="pseudo-container" htmlTag="div">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="testtest.sidebar.sell" as="sell_lable" template="Magento_Theme::youtemps/img.phtml" before="-"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**update**, in your phtml file add this code

```
<h2 style="margin: 0">hot price</h2>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/sell-sidebar.jpg'); ?>" style="margin-bottom: 10px" alt="" />
```

In your Magento_Theme folder add images folder and put in folder your image, next insert to `getViewFileUrl('images/sell-sidebar.jpg');` the path to it is relatively Magento_Theme